# Search for all files with a .sql extension in folders and sub folders

Tags: files, search

I want to search for all files with the .sql extension in folders and sub-folders (recursive).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 37):

Or...

```
find $directory_name -name \*.sql
```

For example

```
find / -name \*.sql
```

Or

```
find ~ \*.sql
```

(where ~ equates to /home/your_username/), or...

```
find /usr/local/share/ \*.sql
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

Run this in the command line:

```
cd / && find | grep '\.sql$'
```

Change '/' to the directory you want to search.

The `find` command is able to accomplish the task without grep (using extra options), but I find the above usage more convenient.

In order, the above command:

1. Changes the current directory to the root directory (`cd /`)
2. Lists all files and directories at and below the current directory (`find`)
3. Filters the files and directories for anything that ends with '.sql' (`| grep '\.sql$'`)

Comment: thanks, can you explain it?  your using grep and passing its output to find?

Comment: Vice versa, actually. I'm using find and passing its output to grep. I added a more detailed explanation above.

Comment: would this work on a Mac also? I tried 'find | grep '\.sql$' and it outputted the usage help info.

Comment: find is a powerful tool and you really do not need to pipe the output to grep. This is a nice link - http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm

Comment: `find` has already filter capabilities

Comment: Why not simply `find / -name '*.sql'`? No need to change the working directory or use additional filter tools for that.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old post, but i am pretty new at this and i've found an easy way to find all files of a certain extension in a directory and its children subdirectories.
Well you first navigate to the `parent Directory` then `find . -name '*.sql'` and that will find you all files with *.sql* extension in the directories and its subdirectories.

In my case i wanted to delete all *.xml* files in the directory and its subdirectories, so what i did more is that i added remove as in here `find . -name '*.xml' | xargs rm`

Hope this help someone :)

Comment: `find` understands the `-delete` command. No need to involve `rm`. Or you can use the `-exec` command to invoke it directly without the detour through a pipe and `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

```
locate -br \\.sql$ | egrep '^/folder/path/'
```

If it is not installed, then previously install it with:

```
sudo apt install mlocate
```

Comment: This requires an up-to-date `mlocate.db` instance which is not set up out-of-the box in Ubuntu (I blieve). Also, why not simply `locate '/folder/path/*.sql'`?

Comment: @DavidFoersterI I tried as you specified but it doesn't work, I guess regex in `locate` has some different setting from regex used in `egrep`

Comment: `locate` matches glob expressions like `/folder/path/*.sql`, not regular expressions.

Comment: sorry, but from `man locate` I get `-r, --regexp REGEXP - Search for a basic regexp REGEXP` so I assumed it was a regex. Anyway I tried your "global expression" but doesn't work, I'm sorry

Comment: Please read at least the first few sentences of the description before you start to cherry-pick from the option synposis: “If `--regex` is not specified, `PATTERN`s can contain globbing characters.” ([source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/locate))

Comment: Sorry dude, when I read your first comment I subconsciously understood that your command had -br , my fault